# From index-based `Table` with different levels to `Map`-based operations?

Tags: list-manipulation

Toy example:

```
ClearAll[f];
Module[{
  a = RandomReal[{}, {2, 3, 4, 5}],
  b = RandomReal[{}, {2, 3, 4, 5}]
  },
 Table[f[ a[[i, j]], b[[i, j, k, l]] ], {i, 2}, {j, 3}, {k, 4}, {l, 5}]
 ]
```

How can it be translated into `Map`-based operations (e.g., `MapThread`) where vectorization may bring in better performance? Or index-based accesses just perform better here?

---

One may suggest using `ConstantArray` to copy data in `a[[i, j]]` to level `k, l` so that `MapThread` could be used:

```
ClearAll[f];
Module[{
  a = RandomReal[{}, {2, 3, 4, 5}],
  b = RandomReal[{}, {2, 3, 4, 5}]
  },
 Table[f[ a[[i, j]], b[[i, j, k, l]] ], {i, 2}, {j, 3}, {k, 4}, {l, 
    5}] ===
  MapThread[f, {
      Map[ConstantArray[#, {4, 5}] &, a, {2}],
      b
    }, 4
   ]
 ]
```

> `True`

but data (at level `j`) may be too large for making copies to be efficient. *I hope the solution can be furthermore generalized for more complicated `f`.*

**Note:** `f` in practice is like:

```
{aij, bijkl} |-> Module[{x, y, ...},
  x = ...;
  y = ...;
  ...
 ]
```

So, it would be better if `f` appears as only itself, purely, like the forementioned `ConstantArray` solution, so we can operate on them without considering their levels and concentrate on their values.

Comment: Does your current implementation do what you want/ if so, what would you like to accomplish by using Map instead of Table? I also do not understand the part about “matching the dimensions of b”: it seems to me that a and already have the same dimensions.

Comment: 1) It does, but I don't think it's efficient enough. 2) I've updated the question. I think the `MapThread` equivalent (with copies) should have a new `a` with dimensions `{2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5}`.

Comment: I asked this question mainly because I think that index-based operations on lists, closely interrelated, are not that **elegant** in *Mma* universe. The pursuit may seem unreasonable or index-based ones may prove to be the most efficient as yet, but I believe one day there will be a more *Mma*-ic way to do this real fast. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the function you're looking for is `Array`:

```
Module[{a = RandomReal[{}, {2, 3, 4, 5}],  b = RandomReal[{}, {2, 3, 4, 5}]},
  Array[f[a[[#1, #2]], b[[##]]]&, {2, 3, 4, 5}]
]
```

Also take a look at `Outer`.

Comment: This is generalizable, but still index-based IMO. It's unlike `MapThread` which is based on, say, the relative positions of lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
amat = Array[a, {2, 3, 4, 5}];
bmat = Array[b, {2, 3, 4, 5}];
```

Using `Map` and `MapThread`

```
MapThread[
  Function[
    {mat1, mat2},
    Map[f[mat1, #] &, mat2, {2}]
  ],
  {amat, bmat},
  2
]
```

And another way using `Outer`, which granted does create more information than is needed and then ignores it.

```
Diagonal /@ Diagonal@Transpose[Outer[f, amat, bmat, 2, 4], {1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but imagine when `f` is a `Module`, where we operate on a lot more matrices and levels. This is hard to generalize.